# Add in onclick the script type

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I need to call the method _trackingEvent if the button was clicked, So I added in the onlick in the button the following code :

```
<button class="btnInscription" 
        onclick="<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');});
                </script>;">
```

when I look in the source of page all code that I put it up is whith red color. I think the problem is with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems :

- you have unescaped " inside your attribute
- you don't need the  tag inside onclick ( onclick code is always javascript code)

the following code should work :

```
onclick="$(function () {GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');});"
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do thinks like this!

Better this way:

```
<button class="btnInscription">blub</button>
<script>
$('.btnInscription').on('click', function() {
GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');
});
</script>
```

make sure to launch JS at the Bottom of your page

Answer (score 0):

You are miss placing it.
The script tag should be in the head of the page and the onclick attribute should call the function :

```js
//this should be in the <head> of the page, inside a <script> tag
function track() {
  //$(function () {GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');});
  console.log('executed when clicked');
}
```

```html
<button class="btnInscription" 
        onclick="track()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try it Once In your File
<button class="btnInscription" id="my-btn">click</button>
<script>
  $(dicument).ready(function(){
  $('#my-btn').click(function(){
    alert('clicked for testing');
    {GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');}
  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also Try Once In Javascript

```js
 
    function testfun() {
      //$(function () {GA._trackEvent('Account','Subscribe','Not Facebook');});
      console.log('If Click == true then it will execute');
    }
```

```html
<button class="btnInscription" 
            onclick="testfun()">click</button>
```